# @Input when passing data is not working angular5

Tags: angular

What I'm trying to do is pass a value from app.component.ts called **`user`** and set the property of the userComponent called **`user`** .

Here are my codes:

**app.component.ts**

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  template: `
    <userComponent [user]="user"></userComponent>
  `
})

export class AppComponent {
  user: User= {name:'martin','age':22};
  constructor(){  }
}
```

**user.component.ts**

```
import { Component, Input } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'nextComponent',
  template: `<i> </i> `
})

export class UserComponent {

    @Input() user: User;

    constructor () {
        console.log('The value  we are receiving here is: ' + this.user)
    }

}
```

I am not recieving anything in console. what is the issue?

Answer (score 4):

Use **`ngOnInit()`** instead of inside constructor

```
export class UserComponent {
    @Input() user:User;

    ngOnInit () {
         console.log('The value  we are receiving here is: ' + this.user);
    }
}
```

Comment: Why `constructor` can't do that ?

Comment: Because the Input   isn't initialized until view is set up. constructor gets called before that